# Is it PEP8-appropriate to replace words into numbers (e.g. book4students, key2value, etc.) in my function names?

Tags: python, pep8

I am relatively new in the programming community, and recently I acknowledged the existence of PEP8, a sort-of codex which aims to improve readability. As listed in the said PEP8 documentation (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), variables and function names should be "lower_case_with_underscores". I wonder if my habit is violating this convention.

Specifically, I often replace words with numbers whenever possible, to abbreviate and shorten the names of variables and functions.

- col4keys
- things2do

I searched for the answer here and there, but nothing seems to be addressing my specific inquiry.

Comment: Numbers are not underscores, so using numbers is clearly a violation of their preference to use only underscores. Is something else about it unclear, or is that what you are asking?

Comment: You may think it is terribly clever to substitute *for* with *4* and then arguing „well 4 is not a word so the underscore rule doesn't apply“ but the point of a style guide is that your code should look familiar to other people. Therefore, you should not only avoid a violation of the style guide's rules, but you should *also* not invent rules not described in the style guide, such as „replace words by numbers that are phonetically similar“.

Comment: Thank you for the kind answers! Oookay... so I'll have to write a code to retrofit all the works I have done last month.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend to use a linter such as [flake8](https://pypi.org/project/flake8/) to find such errors, i.e. PEP-8 violations. It is really good in finding those and pretty much the standart tool as of today.

In your specific case I believe it is not really a violation, so feel free to name your variables this way if you must -- at least `flake8` will not complain.